# kendo ui Rich-Text editor - toolbar displays icons and links

Tags: kendo-ui, rich-text-editor

I want to use Kendo UI rich text Editor inside of ASP.NET page, however when I run the application the editor toolbar is displayed with icons and links, I just want to display icons. How can I fix it?

[View the image with the issue toolbar editor...](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1035254/editorKendo.PNG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally text in editor icons is hided by setting font size to 0 in kendo CSS file:

```
.k-button-group .k-tool-icon{
    font-size: 0;
}
```

If you have such behavior, you have instaled Kedno UI wrong or you are overriding their style.

To check if you have installed it correctly read the kendo instalation manual: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/introduction

If everything is ok you should check in eg. [Firebug tool](http://getfirebug.com/) why this font-size is not set to 0.